# For loop on set - get next element iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

If I loop on a set, and I would like to get current element iterator and next element iterator, how can I do that without using *next()* ?

```
for(auto it = setOfObjects().begin(); it != setOfObjects().end(); ){
            auto current = *it;
            auto next = // ?

}
```

Comment: Why not instead keep track of `current` and `previous`?

Comment: Great idea, how ?

Comment: Is this homework? Please explain what you're doing.

Comment: If you want to peek ahead, you'd need to increment the iterator, make sure it is still not `end` and dereference it. Also, keep in mind that your current for loop is endless.

Comment: I call a method which takes as parameters current object and next object. but when I am doing *next(it), it is nullprt ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add another iterator `prev` to your code and the logic will be:

```
set<int> setOfObjects;
for(auto it = setOfObjects.begin(), previt = it++ ; it != setOfObjects.end(); ++it, ++previt){
  auto prev = *previt;  //which is current
  auto current = *it;   //and this was next
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterators can be examined in the same manner as pointer arithmetic, as below

```
auto next = *(it + 1);
```

Note, that this will require some handling of the case where current is the last element so you don't overstep the iterator

Comment: Won't work if `it` is not `RandomAccessIterator`, e.g. for `std::map`